# How to round up time difference to the nearest seconds with string format?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string.format

I am trying to subtract 2 date time and get time difference in the format of minutes and seconds but how to round up difference to the nearest seconds in string format.

I am having dates like below:

**1)**

```
StartDate= 2016-10-11 04:31:06.513  EndDate=  2016-10-11 04:31:09.457  
   Differrence : 2.94
   Output I am getting is : 00 : 02
   Expected Output :  00 : 03 (round up time to the nearest)
```

**2)**

```
StartDate = 2016-10-14 16:43:18.530 EndDate= 2016-10-14 16:43:50.457 
   Difference : 31.93
   Output I am getting is : 00 : 31
   Expected Output :  00 : 32 (round up time to the nearest)
```

Here is the below linq query, I am trying to calculate time difference:

```
var output = Attendance.Select
                    (
                        t => new
                        {
                            TimeDifference = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).Minutes, (int)t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).Seconds),
                        }
                        ).ToList()
```

[image]

Comment: Caution when reading the answers: Because the question didn't state what should happen with a value like `3.1`, most of the answers interpreted "round up" to mean "any fractional value should be rounded up", so proposed "Math.Ceiling". E.g. `Math.Ceiling(3.1)` => `4`. If you instead want to "only round up values 0.5 and greater", then use "`Math.Round`" instead in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
  DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 10, 11, 04, 31, 06, 513);
  DateTime end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 11, 04, 31, 09, 457);
  var diff = end - start;
  Console.WriteLine($"{diff.Hours:00}:{diff.Minutes:00}:{diff.Seconds + diff.Milliseconds / 1000.0:00}");
```

Answer (score 4):

As Dawnkeeper has told in his answer, you must use [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx), but instead getting the `Seconds` property, you must use [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
var TimeDifference = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)EndDateTime.Subtract(StartDateTime).Minutes, (int)Math.Ceiling(EndDateTime.Subtract(StartDateTime).TotalSeconds));
```

**Edit**
Henrik is right,the above code doesn't work. Let's do it right:

```
var diff=EndDateTime.Subtract(StartDateTime);
double seconds= Math.Ceiling(diff.Seconds+diff.Milliseconds*0.001);
var TimeDifference = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}",diff.Minutes,seconds);
```

I'm on my phone now so i can't try it,but i think it should work

Comment: I'm sorry to write this, but this solution will fail, it the time span exceeds 1 minut, because TotalSeconds includes the entire timespan (years, hours, days, minuts, seconds, milliseconds).

Comment: @HenrikHansen : Can you give me sample input on which this above answer will fail??

Comment: @Learning:       DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 10, 11, 04, 30, 06, 513);
      DateTime end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 11, 04, 31, 09, 457);

Comment: @HenrikHansen:You are right.This is not working with the above input you have given

Comment: You are right @henrikhansen. Edited. I think you should accept his answer instead of mine

Comment: Not `Math.Ceiling`. That would convert `0.001` to `1.0`. Since the goal is to round, use `Math.Round`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Op asks _how to round up difference to the nearest seconds in string format_. If you try the code, you'll see it works just fine :)

Comment: I've never met anyone who would say "round up" to **nearest** and mean that - when dealing with time measurements. I would give 1000:1 odds he meant "round up values 0.5 or greater". But you are right, it is ambiguous as stated. I've now added a caution comment to the question, so that future readers will understand when to use Round vs Ceiling.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve if you read through the question, you'll see several examples that make it clear what OP really wanted. Anyway, this question is from 2016, I was surprised by your comment ;)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve agreed. I was just surprised, but of course i'm glad you clarified the question in case someone falls here seeking for something different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Math.Ceiling()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) function for this.

```
(int)Math.Ceiling(t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).Seconds)
```

But there is another problem. the `Seconds` Property gets full seconds as an integers. You will need the partial seconds as well so the correct answer is:

```
(int)Math.Ceiling(t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Getting error:Call is ambiguos between the following methods or properties : System.Math.Ceiling(double) and System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)

Comment: Correct it like that (int)Math.Ceiling((Double)t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).Seconds)

Comment: @Learning fixed it

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That's exactly what the goal was, Rounding UP

Answer (score 2):

You are saying "round up" and you would get that with Ceiling as already have 
been said. But what would you do if times were?:

2016-10-10 00:00:00.000
2016-10-10 00:00:00.001

Should it be considered as 1 second? Your collection name is attendance, and for an attendance system that wouldn't be the case I guess. If rounding should be up or down or based on a midpoint, then use Math.Round(). ie:

```
var output = Attendance.Select
                (
                    t => new
                    {
                        TimeDifference = 
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(
                        t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).TotalSeconds, 0))
                        .ToString(@"mm\:ss")
                    }
                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes with  this input :2016-10-10 00:00:00.000 2016-10-10 00:00:00.001 the output should be like this: 00 : 01

Comment: Finally someone who says "Round" instead of "Ceiling", given that the stated goal is to Round!

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks. But OP confused me too. He doesn't want round or ceiling really. He says that even a millisecond would count as a minute (above comment). I wasn't sure what he is really after.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - ah ha - I didn't see that comment. very strange. The examples in his question had deltas ending in `.9`, so I assumed he wanted what would normally be wanted when showing times (round). Ah well, I've put a comment on the question, so that future readers will be alerted to `Round` vs `Ceiling`. More important than what one question asker wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

To round up seconds use TotalSeconds instead of Seconds, and surround it with a Math.Ceiling:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-14 16:43:18.530");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-14 16:43:50.457 ");
Console.WriteLine( Math.Ceiling(endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalSeconds));
```

Output: 32

Comment: In what is this answer different to Dawnkeeper or mine?